# Bazel can't build the openssl-sys crate

Tags: rust, bazel

I've got a Rust program that builds fine using Cargo. One of the dependencies is openssl-sys.

I've got bazel set up with the latest Rust rules and crate_universe. When I try to build the program it fails with:

```
--stdout:
cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR
X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR unset
cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR
OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR unset

--stderr:
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { cod
e: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', external/crate_in
dex__openssl-src-111.22.0-1.1.1q/src/lib.rs:507:32
```

The build seems to be trying to copy the openssl source but it isn't where it is expects to find it.

Has anyone seen this problem before? Any hints?